# User location by js map

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps

Is there some kind of map that allows selecting on the fly locations and allows to save them for users? Some Gmap API method for example?

I would like a navigable map instead of standard input text where user can specify their own location by clicking on the location itself if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of options for the javascript programmable client side map processing.  For the Javascript client you could use:

- [Bing Maps SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/)
- [Google Maps SDK](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)
- [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/)
- [GeoExt](http://geoext.org/)
- [PolyMaps](http://polymaps.org/)
- [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/)

Of these I would personally recommend OpenLayers as the most versatile and truly open client side framework.

This is an [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/click.html) of something similar to what you are suggesting using OpenLayers.

You may want to use a geocoding service, google offer a [versatile geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests), but there are others.  One thing to think about is the licensing agreements of the various client side frameworks and APIs vary massively.